# sql joins and finding most common value

Tags: sql, join, sql-server-2014

I have 2 tables, EPISODES and PRESENTERS (please see attached image 1). I want to find the the presenter who has done the most number of shows and display it in a format like this:

TIFF NEEDELL 5

I have already found the most common presenter using this query.

```
select PRESENTERID,count(*) as NumberOfEpisodes from dbo.EPISODES
    group by PRESENTERID
      having count(*) =(select max(NumberOfEpisodes) from 
        (select PRESENTERID,count(*) as NumberOfEpisodes from dbo.EPISODES group by PRESENTERID) EPISODES)
```

Comment: Add tables as text, instead of images, please!

Comment: Please improve the wording of your question, it's not clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Top` and ordering the count in descending  order will do the trick

```
Select Top 1
    PRESENTERID,count(*) as NumberOfEpisodes 
From
   dbo.EPISODES    
Group By PRESENTERID
Order By NumberOfEpisodes DESC
```